# How Call the function from .dll using c# program

Tags: c#

I tried to call the function from .dll file using java native interface ,its successfully working, But I don't know how to call function from .dll using C# ,please advice me on this.

Comment: Please provide the code that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Look at DLLImport attribute in MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664436(v=vs.71).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Example
{

    [DllImport("your_dll_here.dll")]
    static extern int SomeFuncion1(int parm);
    static void Main()
    {
        int result = SomeFunction1(10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a native DLL, you need to add a DLLImport statement, importing the function you want.

The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The attribute looks like this, typically:

```
[DllImport("YourDllNameHere.dll")]
public static extern int YourFunction(int input);
```

This will import a function called YourFunction (which takes an int input, and returns an int) from YourDllNameHere.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your DLL name is `MyLibrary` and `MyFunction` is the function contain in your DLL .

First right click on your `Reference` , browse and add your DLL .
Declare your DLL as a namespace `using MyLibrary;`
And you can call `MyFunction` !

**Or**

Another way ,
you can use this [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) !

Answer (score 0):

Add that dll into your project as a referenced dll into reference folder(right click on references ,add reference then "Browse" to you DLL).then it should be available for to use as you want and just use that dll as follows in the code level.

```
using System;
using YourDllName;

class ExampleClass
{
 //you can use your dll functions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the link provided by Baldrick for DllImport attribute.

This is what I recommend.

1. Download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) (small application exe, no need to install).
2. Open your DLL in the Dependecy Walker to view the exposed entry points of DLL.
3. Declare external call to native function in C# like this.

C#:

```
[DllImport("Your_DLL.DLL", EntryPoint="Function_Entry_Point",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern IntPtr Function1();
```

**Note:**

- If entry point is not specified the function name is considered as the entry point.
- When you run the application make sure the native DLL is in the
  same folder.